# How do I check present viewController or root viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, rootviewcontroller

I have set up my `class` with `UITabBarDelegate` and implemented its `method` `didSelectItem` to detect when a certain `tabBar` item is pressed. Works great. In each `tabBar` item I have one `containerView` that can show a "you have to login"-page if the user is not logged in, and another `containerView` that present `viewControllers` that are embedded in a `navigationController`.

I would like to keep track of the `viewController` that is presented in the current `tab` item, and/or the `root` `viewController` of that `tab`.

I have tried a number of different approaches, but most of them return nil or I can't get it to work. I think the whole `container` situation makes it harder to handle.

It looks something like this:

```
@interface MyTabBarController () <UITabBarDelegate> 

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];

    switch (indexOfTab) {
        case 0: {
            NSLog(@"PRESSIIING %lu", (unsigned long)[[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item]);
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
           NSLog(@"PRESSIIING %lu", (unsigned long)[[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item]);
           break;
        }
        case 2: {
           NSLog(@"PRESSIIING %lu", (unsigned long)[[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item]);

//These return nil
            NSLog(@"AAAAAA %@", ((UINavigationController*)_appD.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController);
            NSLog(@"AAAAAA %@", ((UITabBarController*)_appD.window.rootViewController).selectedViewController);
            NSLog(@"AAAAAA %@", self.navigationController.topViewController);
            NSLog(@"AAAAAA %@", self.navigationController.visibleViewController);

//This returns with a value, but can't get it to work with conditionals, that is, when I'm in root, the else is triggered
            NSLog(@"AAAAAA %@", self.tabBar.window.rootViewController);

            if(!self.tabBar.window.rootViewController) {
                NSLog(@"THIS IS NOT ROOT");

            }else {
                NSLog(@"this is ROOT");
            }

// This returns nil
            ((UINavigationController*)_appD.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController;
            ((UITabBarController*)_appD.window.rootViewController).selectedViewController;

            //Doesn't work
            if([self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] isKindOfClass:[ExperiencesListViewController class]]) {
                           NSLog(@"IS KIND OF CLASS LIST");
                       }
                       if([self.navigationController.viewControllers[0].childViewControllers isKindOfClass:[ExperiencesContainerViewController class]]) {
                           NSLog(@"IS KIND OF CLASS CONTAINER");
                     }
           break;
       }
        case 3: {
           NSLog(@"PRESSIIING %lu", (unsigned long)[[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item]);
           break;
       }
        case 4: {
           NSLog(@"PRESSIIING %lu", (unsigned long)[[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item]);
           break;
       }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

So, what else can I try? Seems like I have to use `self.tabBar.window.rootViewController` in some way, no?

***EDIT*** 
Oh, and I have tried the `tabBarController` delegate but that doesn't trigger. Also, the `tabBar` is constructed programmatically if that helps.
```

Comment: What does "keep track of" mean? What is it that you want to know, and when do you want to know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to have not read your question correctly. Here's what I suggest you do.

All of these view controllers that you're interested in keeping track of: you should have them send a custom notification from within their `-viewDidAppear:` (or `-viewWillAppear:`) method. Then let your ApolloTabBarController object register for that notification. When it gets the notification, you could then store a reference to the view controller. That reference will always point to the active view controller.

In your individual view controllers, do something like the following:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [nc postNotificationName:@"XYZViewControllerDidBecomeActiveNotification"
                      object:self];
}
```

Of course, you would want to use some kind of constant for the notification name.

In your ApolloTabBarController class, register for `XYZViewControllerDidBecomeActiveNotification` and implement something like:

```
- (void)viewControllerDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.activeViewController = [notification object];
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out! :) Wasn't the one who downvoted by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting up each view controller for each of the tabs, set the `tag` property of the `UITabBarItem` to correspond to the index of the view controller in the tab bar's `viewControllers` array.

```
UIViewController* myFirstVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController* mySecondVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

// "self" is your ApolloTabBarController.
[self setViewControllers:@[myFirstVC, mySecondVC]];

myFirstVC.tabBarItem = 
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First" image:nil tag:0];

mySecondVC.tabBarItem = 
    [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Second" image:nil tag:1];
```

Then, you'll be able to grab a reference to view controller.

```
// In your example, your ApolloTabBarController acts as its own delegate.
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    UIViewController* activeVC = 
        [[self viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[item tag]];
}
```